# Polynomial rings commute with localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $A \supseteq \Sigma $ is a multiplicative subset of $A$, how can I prove that there is an isomorphism of rings between $(\Sigma ^{-1} A)[X]$ and $\Sigma ^{-1}  (A[X])$ ?

Answer (score 2):

You should just write down the map and it's inverse, or just right down one direction and prove that it's surjective and injective.  The map $\Sigma^{-1}(A[x]) \to (\Sigma^{-1}A)[x]$ is probably the easier direction to write down.  It's
$$\frac{a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0}{s} \mapsto \frac{a_n}{s}x^n + \cdots + \frac{a_1}{s}x + \frac{a_0}{s}$$

Comment: With this approach one does not only have to write down the map. The main point is that this map is well-defined. And this involves some calculation.

Comment: Obviously, but is pretty trivial to check that the images of elements of $/Sigma$ are invertable under the map I wrote.

Comment: You mean that $A[x] \to (\Sigma^{-1} A)[x]$ maps $\Sigma$ to units? Yes, this is clear, and *therefore* we can apply the universal property and get a homomorphism $\Sigma^{-1} (A[x]) \to (\Sigma^{-1} A)[x]$. This way one does not have to verify by hand that your map is well-defined etc.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you use elements, checking the details involves a lot of computations. But they are not necessary. As with all these basic isomorphisms, one should use universal properties instead. Using the universal properties of quotient algebras and localizations, both sides represent the functor which maps a ring $B$ to the set of pairs $(b,f)$, where $b \in B$ and $f \in \hom(A,B)$ with $f(\Sigma) \subseteq B^*$. This means $\hom(\Sigma^{-1} A[X],-) \cong \hom((\Sigma^{-1} A)[X],-)$, and by Yoneda we are done. If necessary I will add details.

Comment: Can you please add details? Is $B^\ast$ the group of multiplicative units?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write elements of $(\Sigma^{-1}A)[X]$ with a common denominator.